# $_GET MESSES UP URL BECAUSE &

Tags: symbols

How can I get it so that I can use the & in my URL where I'm not bringing in a new $_GET.

www.example.com/index.php?u=brian&art=this%20is%20my%20issue%20&%20enjoying%20issues.

www.example.com/index.php?u=brian&art=this%20is%20my%20issue%20**&**%20enjoying%20issues.

I'm trying to involve the & symbol between text in the URL.

I have a link from another page that is sent to the above link and it won't find it in the database because of "&" symbol or just because the URL is trying to find another $_GET string?.

How can I fix this issue? Sorry if it's too noobish of a questions for your worthyness. I'm also sorry for trying to already google and couldn't find it. But hey! That's how google search results start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%26` instead of `&` inside the URL.